# XSL transform child node values differently

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

Basically, this is the logic I am trying.

For parent nodes (ByFirstNameSearchList or ByLastNameSearchList):

-All Child element values are empty (value1-4) , insert a value of %
-When one or any of the child element has value, replace all siblings with empty value with NOVAL.

I have the following XML:

```
<GetName>
    <ByLastNameSearchList>
        <Value1/>
        <Value2/>
        <Value3/>
        <Value4/>
        <Value5/>
    </ByLastNameSearchList>
    <ByFirstNameSearchList>
        <Value1>String</Value1>
        <Value2>String</Value2>
        <Value3/>
        <Value4/>
        <Value5/>
    </ByFirstNameSearchList>
  </GetName>
```

This is what I want it to look like:

```
<GetName>
    <ByLastNameSearchList>
        <Value1>%</Value1>
        <Value2>%</Value2>
        <Value3>%</Value3>
        <Value4>%</Value4>
        <Value5>%</Value5>
    </ByLastNameSearchList>
    <ByFirstNameSearchList>
        <Value1>String</Value1>
        <Value2>String</Value2>
        <Value3>NOVAL</Value3>
        <Value4>NOVAL</Value4>
        <Value5>NOVAL</Value5>
    </ByFirstNameSearchList>
</GetName>
```

I really appreciate you helping me out. Trust me I have tried everything with my limited XSL knowledge.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="*|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="ByFirstNameSearchList/* | ByLastNameSearchList/*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length(text()) gt 0">
               <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="some $Value in ../* satisfies string-length($Value/text()) gt 0">
               <xsl:text>NOVAL</xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:text>%</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will produce the output you want.

UPDATE:

This version is somewhat more generic, since it doesn't rely on the non-empty elements containing just a string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="*|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="ByFirstNameSearchList/* | ByLastNameSearchList/*">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="string-length(text()) gt 0">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="some $Value in ../* satisfies string-length($Value/text()) gt 0">
            <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:text>NOVAL</xsl:text>
            </xsl:copy>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:text>%</xsl:text>
            </xsl:copy>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

**As simple as this** (both for XSLT 2.0 and XSLT 1.0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*/*[not(node())]">
  <xsl:copy>NOVAL</xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*[not(*/node())]/*">
    <xsl:copy>%</xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<GetName>
    <ByLastNameSearchList>
        <Value1/>
        <Value2/>
        <Value3/>
        <Value4/>
        <Value5/>
    </ByLastNameSearchList>
    <ByFirstNameSearchList>
        <Value1>String</Value1>
        <Value2>String</Value2>
        <Value3/>
        <Value4/>
        <Value5/>
    </ByFirstNameSearchList>
</GetName>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<GetName>
      <ByLastNameSearchList>
            <Value1>%</Value1>
            <Value2>%</Value2>
            <Value3>%</Value3>
            <Value4>%</Value4>
            <Value5>%</Value5>
      </ByLastNameSearchList>
      <ByFirstNameSearchList>
            <Value1>String</Value1>
            <Value2>String</Value2>
            <Value3>NOVAL</Value3>
            <Value4>NOVAL</Value4>
            <Value5>NOVAL</Value5>
      </ByFirstNameSearchList>
</GetName>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The identity rule copies "as-is" every node for which it is selected for execution.
2. A template overrides the identity template for any element that is a grand-child of the top element and that has no children. This copies the element and generates a text-node child with string value the string "NOVAL".
3. A second overriding template, which overrides both the identity template and the first overriding template: matches any elementthat is a grand-child of the top element and whose parent has no child element that has a child node. This copies the element and generates a text-node child with string value the string "%".

**Do Note**:

1. This is a pure "push style" transformation.
2. There are no explicit conditional instructions (no `xsl:choose`, no `xsl:when`, no `xsl:otherwise`), no `xsl:text` and even no `xsl:apply-templates` (except in the identity template).
3. There are no special XPath 2.0 expressions (`some ... satisfies ...`) are used as they are unnecessary.
4. No `string-length()` function is used.

Comment: Thanks That worked like a charm. Just one question. What is the order of execution. So for example, Does the 3rd template ( <xsl:template match="/*/*[not(*/node())]/*">), execute after the 2nd transformation on the 2nd or works independently on its own copy?